# How to minimize React Condition code?

Tags: reactjs

There are three text boxes in my app all three are having same functionality like When onChange Function happened.. I will change the state from empty to the current target value of the text box. I did like below seems to be elementary level. can you please help me to do it in react way?

```
updateBugChange = (e, type) => {
    if(type === 'title')
    {
        this.setState({ bugTitle : e.target.value })
    }
    if(type === 'type')
    {
        this.setState({ bugType : e.target.value })
    }
    if(type === 'description')
    {
        this.setState({ bugDescription : e.target.value })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create the mapping between the types and field names, and then use again computed property feature of JS. This choice is loosely bounded.

```
updateBugChange = (e, type)=>{
    const mapping = {
        title: 'bugTitle',
        type: 'bugType',
        description: 'bugDescription'
    }

    if(!mapping[type]) return;

    this.setState({
        [mapping[type]]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

Comment: The first code has two bugs: `toUpperCase` isn't called, and anyway it would return `bugTITLE`, etc., not `bugTitle`. The second example has `bugTitle` twice in the mapping.

Comment: In addition, for the second example it would be a very good idea to check whether the property name got defined from the mapping; otherwise you'd be wondering why there's a state key called `undefined` if something goes wrong.

Comment: can u please have a look into this https://jsfiddle.net/5yLts8q6/ i didnt add it properly i hope u can understand

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the feedback, and I removed the short version. Updated the code now. I didn't add the `if`, by thinking that the handler will be added to fields by developers, so there is no chance to be called from arbitrary places. But now I added, still I think it is not needed, but good to have guard clause.

Comment: @AKX And then who should handle this error? I am not sure about this throwing error pattern from change handler..

Comment: It's better to fail loudly than to fail silently.